Mathematica: Problem with NumberLinePlot in showing an infinite interval if I specify PlotRange
I need to display an interval ]a,+inf[ with NumberLinePlot:
-NumberLinePlot[{Interval[{3, Infinity}]}]
Writing this code, Mathematica show a line from 3 with an arrow in a range from 0 to 6.
Now I want to specify the plot range but if I add the PlotRange command the arrow indicating that the interval continues to infinity vanishes.
-NumberLinePlot[{Interval[{3, Infinity}]},PlotRange->{2,5]]
How I can restore it? It's a nice representation of the open interval.
